# Jquery Get Child DIV Within DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have the following HTML code within the body:

```
<div id="hidden">

</div>

<div id="mainContianer">
    <div id="firstChildDiv">

    </div>
</div>
```

I am using the following code to get the child

```
$("div:first-child").attr('id')
```

But this returns "hidden" when I want it to return firstChildDiv, I have tried things like...

```
$("div[mainContainer ] div:first-child").attr('id') 
$("div[id=mainContainer ] :first-child").attr('id') 
$("#mainContainer :first-child").attr('id')
```

I know its a simple thing to do, but cant seem to see where I am going wrong...

Thanks

Comment: typo mainContianer -> mainContainer

Comment: Typo in main project to , all your code is correct

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your last selector

```
$("#mainContainer :first-child").attr('id')
```

works fine, if you correct the typo in the HTML (see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bDByd/)). It says `mainContianer` instead of `mainContainer`.

But, anyway, why don't you select simply by the `id`, if that element has an `id`?

```
$( '#firstChildDiv' )
```

Comment: First one to notice congrats too you :)

Comment: From his question you would suggest that he does not know the id beforehand but wants to know the id of the first child div...

Answer (score 6):

```
$('#mainContainer > div:first-child').attr('id');
```

Comment: lol if "undefiend" was on purpose (referring to the typo in the original question, not making fun of you)

Comment: Is your container named "mainContianer" or "mainContainer"? I copied it from your question and I think it's wrong... so updated my answer.

Comment: Its a typo in my code here and my project code, so all your code is correct :)

Comment: Another question: whats the differnece between        $("#mainContainer :first-child").attr('id') and yours what does the > do

Comment: the > div makes it a bit faster if you have multiple levels in your container, because it then does not collect all the elements inside it but just the divs on the first level and gets the :first-child of them http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors http://jsperf.com/first-child-against-div-first-child

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
$("#mainContianer:first-child").attr("id")
```

Check there is no space before ':'

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you have a typo there in your html

```
<div id="mainContianer">
```

should be

```
<div id="mainContainer">
```

Then you can do

```
$("#mainContainer div:first-child").prop('id')
```

This uses [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) rather than [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), which is slower and old jQuery Syntax

Comment: Sorry for confusion is PROP slower or faster than attr?

Comment: There are good reasons: [A perf test](http://jsperf.com/prop-vs-attr-jquery) and [Perfectly well answered so question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Answer (score 1):

this all return you first child of parent--**in your case replace parent by mainContianer**

```
$('#parent').children(":first") 


$('#parent').children(":first-child") 


$( $('#parent').children()[0] ) 


$('#parent').find(":first") 


$('#parent').find(":nth-child(1)")
```

try - [Child Selector (“parent > child”)](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)

```
$("div > div").attr('id')
```

also try out

```
$("div div:first-child")
```

Comment: http://jsperf.com/fastest-get-first ... personally, I like $container.children().first().attr('id'); most, because it's best readable imho and one of the fastest ways.

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me....

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var a =$("#mainContainer div:first-child").attr('id');
    alert(a);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <script>
                function getDiv(){
                alert("answer = "+$('#mainContianer div:first-child').attr('id'));

                }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>

            <div id="hidden"></div>

                 <div id="mainContianer">
                    <div id="firstChildDiv">
                    </div>
                 </div>

                <button onclick="getDiv()">click</button>
    </body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0):

## SCRIPT

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
    $("#MY_BUTTON").click(function(event) {
                 $("div#PARENT_DIV").find("#CHILD_DIV").hide();
             });    
});
</script>
```

## HTML CODE

```
<div id="PARENT_DIV">
        <h1 class="Heading">MY HTML PAGE TEST</h1>
        <br />
        <div id="CHILD_DIV">THIS IS MY CHILD DIV</div>
 </div>

    <div class="MY_BUTTONS"> 
        <a class="MySubmitButton" id="MY_BUTTON">
            <span>Test it!</span>
        </a>
     </div>
```

Comment: Much faster selector: $("#mainContainer :first-child").attr('id')

Answer (score 0):

**for  now in 2020** with jquery it can be like:

```
    function myClickOnDiv(divPrm) {
        let div=$(divPrm);
        let targetElement=div.find('#my_id')
    }
```

if say you div  looks like this:

```
<div onclick=myClickOnDiv(this)><label id="my_id"></label></div>
```