# Get content from id inside id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have HTML like:

```
<div id='content'>
  <div id='price'>$100</div>
  <div id='another'>something</div>
</div>
```

I can get content from id="content" like.

```
vl = document.getElementById("content").value;
```

In this id, I have another `id="price"`. But I cannot get directly content from id="price".

How can I get content from id="price" through `id='content'`.Thank you.

Comment: what's the problem then?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery Get Child DIV Within DIV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11468122/jquery-get-child-div-within-div)

Comment: Id has to be unique on document, you can use classes instead.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery:

```
$("#price").text();
```

javascript:

```
document.getElementById("price").innerHTML;
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QEBx3/)**

Answer (score 2):

You can use as below :

```
vl = document.getElementById("price").innerHTML;
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/butani_vijay010/8U68h/) - Check it out

YOu can also use jquery using **.html()** or **.text()** method

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
$('#content').html().find('#price').html();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
var parent = document.getElementById('content');
var childNodes = parent.childNodes;
for(var i = 0, len = childNodes.length;i<len;i++){
    if(childNodes[i].id === "price") {
        alert(childNodes[i].innerHTML);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using jquery,

```
 $("#content > #price").text();
```

Comment: I don't find this works. But instead, this does: `$("#content #price").text();`

Answer (score 1):

You can get value of price directly as :

```
v2 = document.getElementById("price").value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the child element through parent element... that is your question right.. i solve it with jquery [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6LbmL/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var tem = $('#content').children('#price').text();
    alert(tem);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

using Jquery,

```
v1= $('#content').html();
v2=v1.find('#price');
v3=v1.find('#another')
```

Answer (score 1):

IDs should only be used when there is one of that item on the page. You will have no other chance as to re-assign your `IDs`, or alternatively using the `class` attribute.

Try this way to select,

```
var vl = document.getElementById("content").getElementsByClassName("price")[0];
```

HTML

```
 <div id='content'>
   <div class='price'>$100</div>
   <div class='another'>something</div> 
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/C3C4x/1/

```
var price = document.querySelector("#content #price").innerHTML;

console.log(price);
```